# Effect of electroplating on resistance

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, conductors

How will resistance of a wire be affected if I electroplate it with copper will it decrease ? And if yes then will the decrease be significant?
I need to find a topic for my project I thought it might be a unique concept as far as my school goes but just to be assured for it.
PST: can u post an equation if possible

Comment: FYI, I don't think you should be motivated to try something purely based on the results.  This seems like it would be an interesting topic, regardless of the outcome.  It would show good scientific thinking to be able to come up with a hypothesis and test it without knowing the expected results beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the composition of the wire, but let's suppose it is pure copper; and let's also suppose you are electroplating it with pure copper.  The resistance of a copper wire is inversely proportional to its cross-sectional area.  When you increase the diameter of the wire by adding an electroplated thickness of copper, you are increasing the cross-sectional area and therefore decreasing the resistance.

If the composition of the electroplated material is different from that of the wire, you will still decrease the resistance because you're adding a further path for electricity.  In this case, though, you need to figure out the cross-sectional area of just the electroplated layer, calculate its resistance, and treat it as a resistance connected in parallel to the original wire.  I'll leave the math to you: just look up [parallel resistance](https://www.swtc.edu/Ag_Power/electrical/lecture/parallel_circuits.htm).

By the way, AC resistance and DC resistance are often different because high-frequency AC current tends to be concentrated at the surface of a wire.  In that case, electroplating a very low-resistivity layer onto a higher-resistivity wire can result in a dramatic reduction of AC resistance.

Answer (score 1):

> How will resistance of a wire be affected if I electroplate it with
>   copper will it decrease ?

Almost always, yes, assuming the wire you're electroplating onto isn't copper. As McGrew notes above, even in that case it will still go down a bit.

However, it is very important to consider the [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect). This causes AC power to sort of "push itself" to the outside of the wire. So in that case you might imagine that the copper might help a lot.

To put that in perspective, the wires you see on overhead high voltage towers consists of an inner steel cable wrapped in aluminum. Due to the skin effect, the current is carried in the outer aluminum layer. Why do this? Because the wires heat up as you run more current through them, and aluminum goes soft are a relatively low temperature, whereas steel allows you to work at higher temps. I've read of efforts to replace the inner steel core with carbon fibre, but I'm not sure anyone has actually done that on a large scale.

So I think you have an EXCELLENT question for a project. Just be sure to use AC during your measurements.